# Changes rows of the matrix

Tags: c, pointers

I have an array of structs. Actually, it is a 2d-array but an unusual 2d array.
I am allocating memory on stack:

```
#define MAX_VERTICES 5068
struct ARRAY_FIX {
    int ele[MAX_VERTICES];
    int size;
    int first;
};
ARRAY_FIX C[MAX_VERTICES];
 
int main() {
//...
}
```

So, I need to replace one row with another one (actually, i need this operation to be performed for sorting rows by some criteria).

[image: Replacing of the rows]

How is it possible to perform? As I understand, if I use this code:

```
С[i] = C[j];
```

In this code, the operator "=" will copy all array, won't it? I needn't it, I want to change the rows by changing the pointer

How can I do it?

Comment: I need to replace rows. If I have 2d-array (arr[][]), I will do this: *(arr+i) = (*arr + i); Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, each row is represented by `struct ARRAY_FIX` object. If you want to be able to work with these rows by using references (changing the order of rows by swapping pointers etc.), your 2D array must be stored in a way that allows you to do that.

Possible solution is to change your 2D array to **an array of pointers to `struct ARRAY_FIX`** so that when you call `С[i] = C[j];` only the reference (address of your object) is copied, not an object itself.

Also note, that you should worry about the performance and try to make your program faster only when it's really needed. ***It's much easier to make a correct program fast than it's to make a fast program correct.***

Comment: would not the following work?
`Array Fix temp; temp=C[i]; C[i]=C[j]; C[j]=temp; `?

Comment: I really need a very faster program, that's why I am asking. Otherwise, I wouldn't use this structure.

Comment: @Kraken: Without changing the definition of `C` array, it would copy objects which is slower than copying references to those objects.

Comment: @user565447: That's exactly my point. You are looking for **very fast program**, but you don't know whether the one you have now is slow. Sounds like **premature optimization**.

Comment: Thanks all people have taken part in the discussion, I have read that if the object was allocating on stack, there is no pointer to it, that is the pointer is counted by programm. So the only solution is to use array of pointers, but I need a lot of refactoring. What a pity!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of pointers to `struct ARRAY_FIX` and just switch the pointers into the array.

> I am allocating memory on stack.

An object declared at file scope is usually NOT on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

as said before

> Possible solution is to change your 2D array to an array of pointers
>   to struct ARRAY_FIX

here after how to do it:

```
#define MAX_VERTICES 5068
struct ARRAY_FIX {
    int ele[MAX_VERTICES];
    int size;
    int first;
};
ARRAY_FIX *C[MAX_VERTICES];

int main() {
int i;
ARRAY_FIX *p;
//...
for (i=0;i<MAX_VERTICES;++i)
{
    C[i] = malloc (sizeof(ARRAY_FIX ));
    //...
}
//...
p = C[1];
C[1] = C[2];
C[2] = p;
//...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to allocate dynamic memory. I can't understand, why I can't use the same operation, not allocating dynamic memory? The first element is a pointer to all array,isn't it?